Estimate parameters of a log-normal distribution from censored data for simulation
I have the following model
$$Y=X_1/c_1+X_1*X_2/c_2+X_3/c_3+X_3*X_4/c_4.$$
Where I know that $X_1$ and $X_3$ follow different but know normal distributions, $c_1\dots,c_4$ are known constants and $X_2,X_4$ follow different unknown log-normal distributions. I want to do a Monte-Carlo simulation to estimate the quantiles of $Y$.
I have some data to estimate the distributions of $X_2,X_4$ but that Data is left- and right censored. It might look like this:
$$\begin{matrix} <0.2 & 0.1 & >4 & 0.7 & 0.9 & <0.3 &>0.7 &0.3 &<0.1 \end{matrix}$$
In the better case I have 60 datapoints of which 10 are censored. In the worse case I have 21 of which 9 are censored.
With the censored data I can estimate the parameters of the log-normal distributions $X_2,X_4$. I do this with the R package fitdistrplus. For $X_2$ I get for example:
$$\begin{matrix} & \text{estimate} & \text{Std. Error}\\ \text{meanlog} & -1.5& 0.2\\ \text{sdlog} & 1.8 & 0.19 \end{matrix}$$
I would like to incorporate the uncertainty of the estimate in my model. Is there a natural way of doing this? My idea was to vary the parameters of the lognormal distribution accordingly to the error. So I could pick different the $\text{meanlog}$'s I use for my simulation form $\mathcal{N}(-1.5,0.2^2)$ and $\text{sdlog}$'s from $\mathcal{N}(-1.8,0.19^2)$. But the choice of a normal distribution here seems arbitrary. If the data would not be censored the t-distribution and the $\chi^2$-distribution would seem natural to pick from (if I am right?) but how does this work with censored data? Should I ignore the computed error and use them any way? But with how many degrees of freedom? Or is this enough data to use the normal approximation? Or is there a different way?

Maximum likelihood methods, as used for fitting distributions to censored data, have an asymptotic multivariate normal distribution of the parameter estimates. See Wikipedia. With small data sets like yours there's no assurance that a normal distribution is correct, but it's typically taken to be the case in practice (for example in survival analysis) for performing Wald tests on the parameter estimates and for getting confidence intervals for predictions.
If you do work with the asymptotic normal estimates, remember that the mean and standard deviation values aren't estimated independently. You need to sample from their joint bivariate distribution, with parameters obtained by applying the vcov() function to your fitdistcens object.
The fitdistrplus package provides a bootdistcens() function to re-fit the function to multiple bootstrap samples of your censored data. If you don't want to rely on the assumption of normality, you could instead sample directly from a large number of bootstrapped estimates.
